# Tomcat multiple requests same user, same url (is that caching? thread keep-alive?)

Tags: multithreading, tomcat, caching, optimization, keep-alive

I am working with a new server which I have total control of my Tomcat 7 configurations.

I've optimized my memory usage, permgem space and bzip compression which really is making the difference... but I noticed something in my old server (which I can't control or see the configs)... it seems to be using some kind of caching? or maybe it is just the way the threads are being allocated to handle the requests, I don't know...

By using the Firebug, more specifically, at Net panel, I got this from my old server:

[image]

First request from a "tough" process took almost 6s and then the next 2 seems to be cached opening it a lot faster.

In my new server, however, each request seems to be handled by a new thread every time (my guess) and it is going through the tough process each time...

[image]

Well, my question is... what can I do in my Tomcat in order to achieve the same results from the old server? Besides my optimizations (memory, compression) is there anything else you could recommend?

That would be all by now, thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: What do you mean "tough process"? Is the response delivered after heavy processing?

Comment: Sorry about my English, it is not my main language. Btw, it is the heavy processing itself. On my new server the servlet executes its tasks in every request. In the other hand, in the old server looks like it just delivery the last response without executing all the tasks again... Is that more clear? thanks for the reply.

Comment: The web application i.e. your servlet code is the same in both cases?

Comment: Cratylus, it is the same, but I just found the answer, it is this expiry headers mentioned by girlytech59. Btw thanks for the helping.

Comment: kapep, thanks for editing my images in the topic =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably old server had expiry headers set. you can do that through a Tomcat Valve or if you have a fronting Apache Httpd you can do it there

Comment: Thanks girlytech59, that is what I was looking for...Just found this website with other good tips on this topic and optimizations in general: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires